# List with an Image and MultiSpanButton

Tags: java, image, codenameone

I want to display a list of data with an image.

I can load the image into CSS but I have little control the image's size and placement.

I can set an image on a label using CSS, but I cannot set the labels size so it sets itself up with a width of 0 and height of 0 (making it invisible).  If I set the width and height in the CSS or in the Java code before the Label is added to the form the setting is simply ignored.

```
Container list = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
list.setScrollableY(true);

// resultset is a List<Map<String, Object>> returned by an API
for (Map<String, Object> obj : resultset) {
    String id = obj.containsKey("id") ? (String) obj.get("id") : "";

    String startDate = "";
    String s = (String) obj.get("start_date");
    if ((s != null) && (!s.isEmpty())) {
       try {
          long l = Long.parseLong(s);

          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
          startDate = sdf.format(new Date(l));
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    String name = obj.containsKey("name") ? (String) obj.get("name") : "";
    String description = obj.containsKey("description") ? (String) obj.get("description") : "";
    String eventType = obj.containsKey("event_type") ? (String) obj.get("event_type") : "";

    Container c = new Container(BoxLayout.x());
    Label img = new Label();
    // img.setWidth() img.setHeight() has no effect here
    img.setIconUIID("meeting"); // I will change this dynamically depending on the eventType later
    c.add(img);

    SpanMultiButton mb = new SpanMultiButton();
    mb.setTextLine1(startDate + ": " + name);
    mb.setTextLine2(description);
    mb.setTextLine3(eventType);

    mb.addActionListener(ee -> {
       // TODO: Handle the click on the item
    });

    c.add(mb);
    list.add(c);
}

form.add(CN.CENTER, list);
```

The CSS for "meeting"

```
meeting {
    background-image: url("img/meeting.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And the meeting.png file is in src/main/css/img.  if I set it as the UIID on the MultiSpanButton I can see the image in the background, so I know it's not a problem with the file or the location of the file.

I basically want to have the list show up something like this:

```
+------------------------+
| IMG  | SpanMultiButton |
+------------------------+
| IMG  | SpanMultiButton |
+------------------------+
| IMG  | SpanMultiButton |
+------------------------+
| IMG  | SpanMultiButton |
+------------------------+
```

IMG, however, doesn't show and SpanMultiButton appears on the very left.  I can see that the IMG is there if I inspect it in the simulator.

I cannot get the GuiBuilder to open so I cannot put the images into the resource file to try to open and add it as an image.

The above code works, apart from the fact that the image (background of the label) is not shown because the labels size is 0 x 0.

Answer (score 0):

Codename One doesn't support CSS layout since it conflicts with the high level layout manager logic so elements such as width and height are always ignored. Furthermore, width/height properties will only include valid values after layout is performed.

You shouldn't use `setWidth` and similar APIs as they are designed for use by the `LayoutManager` which will override your settings. Even if it does work it will break when the phone is rotated.

In Codename One images that aren't purely design images (backgrounds etc.) are considered part of the code not of the CSS as they apply to all the elements. Since your image appears in a list of elements it's content, not design and is part of that Java code.

In this case if you just want an icon use `setIcon` and provide an image. If the image is hardcoded in the CSS you can still include it there and then get it from the `Resources` class as it will be a part of the default theme.

If the image is content you can use classes like `URLImage` etc. to fetch it dynamically. Both will size the label correctly with the image.

Comment: How would I get the file into the Resources file (theme.res?).  I cannot open GUIBuilder in my IntelliJ project - The Codename One option is disabled in the right click menu, and File|New does not offer me any Codename One settings.

Comment: I've tried to use URLImage to load the file from the src (and other directories), but always get a Stream:null error.

Comment: I managed to add my images to a theme.res file by copying a theme.res file from a sample app and placing it in src/main/assets.  Then I could double click the file and add images.  I have yet to test loading images from the theme.res file.

Comment: ` Resources r = Resources.openLayered("theme");
 Image i = r.getImage("meeting.png");
 c.add(i);`
 
Throws an exception that the theme.res file was not found. (I have tried it in src and src/main)

Comment: No. Just include the files in a CSS style like you already did. Once you did that the file will implicitly be a part of the `theme.res`. See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_import_multiple_images_in_single_selector). Use `Resources.getSystemResource().getImage("meeting.png");` to fetch an image from the CSS.